# Why does this polynomial function give drastically different results, depending on the amount of points I plot?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, polynomials

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def func(x):
    return 5.61929612e+02 + 6.81573974e-01*x - 4.10728802e-03*x**2 + 1.87813061e-05*x**3 - 5.48199867e-08*x**4 + 8.41432160e-11*x**5 - 6.22733129e-14*x**6 + 1.76282052e-17*x**7

x_values = np.arange(0, 750, 1)
plt.plot(x_values, func(x_values))
plt.show()
```

When I run this code this is the result:

[image]

However when I increase the resolution:

```
x_values = np.arange(0, 750, 0.1)
plt.plot(x_values, func(x_values))
plt.show()
```

I get this:
[image]

I am using Python 3.7 and the up to date versions of pyplot and numpy. (16.06.2020)
I have used the fix of increasing the resolution but this does not make any sense to me. Is there someone who can help?

Comment: The problem with your first curve is that the x_values are interpreted as integers. You can solve it with `x_values = np.arange(0, 750, 1, dtype=np.float)`. Or by adding a decimal point in one of the numbers (e.g. `np.arange(0, 750, 1.)`).

Comment: Thank you very much, that fixed it. I still don't understand why this would be a problem though. Does Python change every number that comes up during calculation to an integer, if the input is one?

Comment: It is integer because all values involved are integers. What is weird is how numpy decides to return integer values for a function made up of float calculations. What seems to happen is that `x**7` is calculated using integers (giving overflow), and only then convert the expression to float.